# Excel Integration With C#.NET

Tags: .net, excel

I have developed a Web Application using VS.NET 2010 AND MS SQL 2008 having Multiple Master Detail forms. Now my client wants to Add/Update Data using Excel Sheet also. He want to download data in Excel and upload it after addition/deletion/updation. Please recommand best possible approach for this functionality.
I have seen Oracle ADF Desktop Integration Feature providing similar functionality

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_59/jdtut_11r2_59_1.html

Is there any thing similar to that avaliable in ASP.NET.

Thanks

Comment: Probably best to use the OOXML SDK. Don't use the Automation stuff, it's prone to failure in non-interactive environments.

Comment: Use Open XML SDK. http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/donovanf/Introduction-to-Open-XML-SDK-20-Part-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) to import the data to dataset in your application.